# How can we use a value from component state while exporting in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

my class component is like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

let EXPORT_TITLE = "";

class EditCook extends Component {
  state = {
    title: "page title"
  };

  render() {

    EXPORT_TITLE = this.state.title; // <---------- Here I am setting the value of the global variable

    return <div>SOME JSX</div>;
  }
}

console.log(EXPORT_TITLE); // <--------- I want to access the value from components state here. 

export default EditCook;
```

I want to access the **value** of **title** from the components state outside the component.
The actual use case is that I have a Higher order component where I need to send the title of the page while exporting like this.

```js
export default withPageSpec(EditCook, {
  title: EXPORT_TITLE,
});
```

[Here is the codesandbox link for the above](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-rgb-vvpem?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Please, don't do that. You should export functions, classes and constants, but not mutable values. If you can't lift your state up, use a ref as the last resource. Avoid singletons in your application https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Okay, but how can I access the ref outside the component? I want to use the state value in the same file while exporting. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Tell me if this helps you. Note that a HOC is not very helpful if you simply wanna forward some props. https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-mcnulty-o6k54?file=/src/App.jsx

Comment: Thank you, I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure there is a better way to organize your code, so you would not have to to this, like using redux, but to answer you question directly, you could export and object and set the value inside the object.

```
export const EXPORT_TITLE = {current: ''}

class EditCook extends Component {
  state = {
    title: "page title"
  };

  render() {

    EXPORT_TITLE.current = this.state.title; // <---------- Here I am setting the value of the global variable

    return <div>SOME JSX</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to use the EXPORT_TITLE in the same file, just outside the component

Comment: It works. And so does your implementation in this case. But you are logging it before the value was assigned

Comment: How can I get the value once its set?

Comment: since you are using it for HOC your component will be invoked after HOC runs, so the value will only be assigned after you are done with HOC invokation. Assuming you understand this and need an access to the value later on in the HOC, you can `import { EXPORT_TITLE } from 'path/to/your/file'` and access its current value when available (say after a ajax call)

Comment: does this answer your question?